# Use curl libraries without install them

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to use the curl libraries in c++ to download some files with Ubuntu, it has to run in a sever but I can't install the packages because I don't have the privileges on that machine. How can I use those libraries without installing them? 
Thanks.

Comment: Download and build it yourself ? It is pretty straightforward to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take curl library from your development machine, put it near your binary and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point out system to where get `curl` library

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/where/your/curl/library ./your-executable
2. You can build curl library by hands in form of static library and link with your application.